# Creating Tables with varying size in array

Tags: openpyxl

I am using a query to pull data from another source and then using openpyxl to create and excel table to be able to analyze the data. My array varies in size and I am trying to figure out how to vary the size of my table.

In creating the table and using `ref="A1:B4"`, I am looking to call on the size of my array to populate the ref.

I have tried using ref=none and my excel file then gets corrupt and I get errors.

```
tab = Table(displayName="Table1", headerRowCount=0, ref="A1:B54")
```

My table size will vary and I want to use the size of the array to establish ref.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `ref="A1:B4` with the size of your array. Use any size if you do not now the array size beforehand. You can resize an existing table later by changing the ref. Tables can be found from the worksheets ._tables.

```
for table in worksheet._tables:
    if table.displayName == "SalesTable":
        table.ref = "A1:C10"
```